# image uploader for ruby/jruby

Tags: ruby, file-upload

are there any libraries out there that will take a photo upload and push it to S3 without writing temp files to the disk? Photo upload is a main feature on our site, and we do not want diskIO to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I think all of the file uploaders will create a temporary file on your server.

Comment: It makes sense that they move this to disk to avoid bloated heap memory. But i have to wonder if a site like that will start being a disk IO intensive and that would the bottleneck. I suppose, we can go with a traditional solution, deployed on disk with a high iops assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my thoughts in the comments above but thinking outside the box you might have a chance of avoiding using local temp files altogether by using https://www.filepicker.io/ With them you add some javascript to your app and let them handle the io on their disks. According to their docs they push your files directly to your S3 bucket without ever going through your app's server. This might be what you're looking for but it comes with their price tag. Might be worth it if you don't want to worry about shuffling user files.

Comment: thats a great find. Thank you. I hope i have the problem of hitting their top tier pricing one day. It'd be a good problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for these: [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) or [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly). There is an option in carrierwave [see this](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Delete-cache-garbage-directories) for deleting temporary cache directories.